# PDO with parameter

Tags: php, pdo

I would like to have various option to change $this_var that contain different fieldname
such as 'apple'=1 or 'orange'=1, is it possible?

```
$statement->prepare(SELECT * table WHERE $this_var = 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
$this_var = 'apple';
$statement->prepare("SELECT * table WHERE $this_var = 1");
```

the query would be `SELECT * table WHERE apple = 1;`

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter my question is quite similar to this which ask if it can subtitute table name but in my case, would be using variable to subtitute fieldname.

Comment: I think you are asking me if you can use placeholders or tokens like `:table` to replace table names just like data values in PDO. (this is not clear from your question however) In this case it is not possible. Simply sanitise the table name and insert it into the query as I have done above in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

No, you cannot have prepared statements with variable field names.